# Every Item is colliding but 1

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, collider

In my game I have a *BULLET, MOONS, STARS, and A SHIP*. I shoot bullets from the ship and hit stars or moons and collisions occur. Yet when a moon runs into my ship there is no detection even though I set the a Collider for 2D on both of them.

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col) {
        Debug.Log (this.transform.tag);//moon hit ship not printing
        Debug.Log (col.transform.tag);//only bullet hit moons and stars
    }
```

Heres a quick snippet
https://i.gyazo.com/acc0bbf5d2aab994db3a6598bfd206aa.mp4

Comment: I noticed my bullet moves with addForce from rigid body so im going to assume i need make my character move using Rigidbody2D

Comment: can you please give us more example of your problem ? like picture , video , ect

Comment: It was quick but the moon colliding at the end
https://i.gyazo.com/ffa7b53537a2e0a75eea7026a55a2b28.mp4

Comment: Its on the bottom left make sure the seek bar isnt covering it, the moon covered about half the ship

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/acc0bbf5d2aab994db3a6598bfd206aa.mp4

Comment: Yep the tab name is shup :P I tagged all my objects

Comment: No go. The problem is the collision is not being detected not, it wont print

Comment: have you tried to hit your own bullet to ship ? to test where the problem are

Comment: Bullet shoots from ship, if there was a collision ship and bullet would appear on console also

Comment: just try , im curious if the problem was at the ship itself , when the bullet hit something , its debugged the object tag that it hit , try to hit your own ship with bullet and tell me the result

Comment: Everytime i shoot, i hit the ship. The spawn for the bullet is inside the shit so when it leaves it is forced to collide

Comment: I tried and didnt worked, i put the prefab for the bullet into game and ran over it with ship and nothing :c

Comment: then there is problem with your ship collider -run out of idea-

Comment: Yeah I remember it working when i set the rigidbody to not be a trigger so it would get hit and move down but count as a collision and I was like WTF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So comparing bullet and player I learned bullet worked because it wasn't a trigger so I set my player object to not be a trigger and now it works, Im embarrassed Lol.